# SQL window functions - how to assign a trip number

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a transactions table with columns user_id, transaction_timestamp, transaction_currency. Assume that home currency is 'ABC' and hence domestic transactions are all denoted by transaction_currency = 'ABC'. I want to define another column to the table denoting the trip number of each use based on the progression of transaction_currency. Given the ordered (by timestamp) list of transaction for a specific user, a new trip starts at each transaction where transaction_currency is not 'ABC' and the immediately previous transaction had transaction_currency = 'ABC'. Once a trip starts, all transactions are part of the same trip number until the immediately next transaction has transaction_currency = 'ABC'. Again, the very next time another currency appears (other than 'ABC'), a new trip number is assigned to all transactions until it is ended by another transaction having transaction_currency = 'ABC'. For all transactions with transaction_currency = 'ABC', trip number can be defaulted to 0. For others, trip number starts from 1 and increments by 1 for every new trip.

Here is the expected result for a sample dataset

| USER | TXN_TIMESTAMP | TRANSACTION_CURRENCY | TRIP_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ABC | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | AED | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | AED | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | AED | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | ABC | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | ABC | 0 |
| 1 | 7 | AED | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | AED | 2 |
| 1 | 9 | AED | 2 |
| 1 | 10 | AED | 2 |
| 1 | 11 | ABC | 0 |
| 1 | 12 | ABC | 0 |
| 1 | 13 | ABC | 0 |
| 1 | 14 | THB | 3 |
| 1 | 15 | THB | 3 |
| 1 | 16 | THB | 3 |
| 1 | 17 | USD | 3 (trip num should not change here) |
| 1 | 18 | USD | 3 |
| 1 | 19 | ABC | 0 |
| 1 | 20 | AED | 5 |

I know this can be done by window functions, but I am a beginner.

I tried the following

```
WITH TripStarts AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    transaction_timestamp,
    transaction_currency,
    LAG(transaction_currency, 1, 'ABC') OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY transaction_timestamp) AS prev_currency,
  FROM
    transactions
)

SELECT
  *, 
  CASE
    WHEN transaction_currency = 'ABC' THEN 0
    WHEN transaction_currency != 'ABC' AND prev_currency = 'ABC' THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY transaction_timestamp)
  END AS trip_number
FROM TripStarts
```

But the trip_number keeps getting incremented for each transaction in the same trip.

Awesome if this can be done by commonly used window functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps problem, i usually do a two step counter + sum solution for that:

```sql
select *
,   case when transaction_currency = 'abc' then 0 else  SUM(flag) over(partition by [user] order by txn_timestamp rows between unbounded preceding and current row) end as trip_number_new
from (
    select *, case when lag(transaction_currency) over(partition by [user] order by txn_timestamp) = 'ABC' and transaction_currency <> 'abc' then 1 else 0 end as flag
    from (
        VALUES  (1, 1, N'ABC', N'0')
        ,   (1, 2, N'AED', N'1')
        ,   (1, 3, N'AED', N'1')
        ,   (1, 4, N'AED', N'1')
        ,   (1, 5, N'ABC', N'0')
        ,   (1, 6, N'ABC', N'0')
        ,   (1, 7, N'AED', N'2')
        ,   (1, 8, N'AED', N'2')
        ,   (1, 9, N'AED', N'2')
        ,   (1, 10, N'AED', N'2')
        ,   (1, 11, N'ABC', N'0')
        ,   (1, 12, N'ABC', N'0')
        ,   (1, 13, N'ABC', N'0')
        ,   (1, 14, N'THB', N'3')
        ,   (1, 15, N'THB', N'3')
        ,   (1, 16, N'THB', N'3')
        ,   (1, 17, N'USD', N'3 (trip num should not change here)')
        ,   (1, 18, N'USD', N'3')
        ,   (1, 19, N'ABC', N'0')
        ,   (1, 20, N'AED', N'5')
    ) t ([USER],TXN_TIMESTAMP,TRANSACTION_CURRENCY,TRIP_NUMBER)
    ) x
```

Step 1:

Create a flag that changes when you want to get a new trip number. In this case, we want it to happen when previous trip was ABC and current trip isn't ABC: `case when lag(transaction_currency) over(partition by [user] order by txn_timestamp) = 'ABC' and transaction_currency <> 'abc' then 1 else 0 end`

Step 2:

Summarize the flags over ordered by timestamp to get the trip number. For ABC, we set trip number to zero:

`case when transaction_currency = 'abc' then 0 else SUM(flag) over(partition by [user] order by txn_timestamp rows between unbounded preceding and current row) end`

Output:

| USER | TXN_TIMESTAMP | TRANSACTION_CURRENCY | TRIP_NUMBER | flag | trip_number_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | AED | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | AED | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | AED | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 6 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 7 | AED | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | AED | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 9 | AED | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 10 | AED | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 11 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 12 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 13 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 14 | THB | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 15 | THB | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 16 | THB | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 17 | USD | 3 (trip num should not change here) | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 18 | USD | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 19 | ABC | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 20 | AED | 5 | 1 | 4 |

Note, that output doesn't match on the last trip, but i think that's a mistake in your data

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for explaining it so clearly :) Please feel free to share more examples/resources that deal with gaps problems or other advanced SQL problems if you have them handy.