# Sum time of consecutive rows with condition of filed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In a table organised like this

| EventTime | Device | State | UpTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 04:48:49.080 | device_1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 04:49:14.097 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 04:49:45.753 | device_1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 04:50:34.127 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 04:51:25.770 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 04:52:45.423 | device_1 | 2000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 04:55:05.253 | device_1 | 3004 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 04:55:28.613 | device_1 | 2018 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:19:28.623 | device_1 | 3004 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:20:08.623 | device_1 | 2000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:20:21.997 | device_1 | 2016 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:21:35.450 | device_1 | 2000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:21:48.823 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:22:09.027 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:22:42.293 | device_1 | 3004 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 05:23:07.310 | device_1 | 3004 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:24:05.060 | device_1 | 2000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:24:18.403 | device_1 | 2016 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:24:25.310 | device_1 | 2016 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:25:34.980 | device_1 | 2000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:25:44.980 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:26:08.543 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:26:55.140 | device_1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 05:27:20.140 | device_1 | 1000 | 0 |
| 2024-01-01 05:27:21.890 | device_1 | 1000 | 1 |

I need to count how many times I change the "UpTime" field from state 1 to state 0, and how long the state 0 lasts until the next change to 1 of the UpTime field

Example:
If we consider the table above, we would have

| Device | EventTimeDown | EventTimeUp | TotalPeriodSecond |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Device1 | 2024-01-01 04:49:14.0967985 | 2024-01-01 04:49:45.7530473 | 31 |
| Device1 | 2024-01-01 04:50:34.1280488 | 2024-01-01 05:22:42.2938957 | 1928 |
| Device1 | 2024-01-01 05:23:07.3095144 | 2024-01-01 05:26:55.1395437 | 228 |
| Device1 | 2024-01-01 05:27:20.1395443 | 2024-01-01 05:27:21.8895430 | 1 |

I tried to use a ***cross apply*** but I cannot isolate the date of the first event with UpTime = 0 by deleting subsequent records with UpTime = 0 because I do not need them.

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Looks like a gaps and islands problem; a search of this terminology will likely give you a wealth of useful resources.

Comment: OK sorry I fixed the post and removed the images

Comment: Use `LAG` to get the previous row's value, then sum the `datediff`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL window functions - how to assign a trip number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77613332/sql-window-functions-how-to-assign-a-trip-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previous comments, working example:
[SQL Fiddle](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=0f4e97e8-5a68-46ec-9d76-a13636796fd5)

```
select 
    *
INTO #Events
FROM (
    VALUES
        ('2024-01-01 04:48:49.080', 'device_1', 1000, 1),
        ('2024-01-01 04:49:14.097', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 04:49:45.753', 'device_1', 1000, 1),
        ('2024-01-01 04:50:34.127', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 04:51:25.770', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 04:52:45.423', 'device_1', 2000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 04:55:05.253', 'device_1', 3004, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 04:55:28.613', 'device_1', 2018, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:19:28.623', 'device_1', 3004, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:20:08.623', 'device_1', 2000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:20:21.997', 'device_1', 2016, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:21:35.450', 'device_1', 2000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:21:48.823', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:22:09.027', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:22:42.293', 'device_1', 3004, 1),
        ('2024-01-01 05:23:07.310', 'device_1', 3004, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:24:05.060', 'device_1', 2000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:24:18.403', 'device_1', 2016, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:24:25.310', 'device_1', 2016, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:25:34.980', 'device_1', 2000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:25:44.980', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:26:08.543', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:26:55.140', 'device_1', 1000, 1),
        ('2024-01-01 05:27:20.140', 'device_1', 1000, 0),
        ('2024-01-01 05:27:21.890', 'device_1', 1000, 1)
) q (EventTime, Device, State, UpTime)

SELECT Device, EventTimeDown, EventTime EventTimeUp, DATEDIFF(SECOND, EventTimeDown, EventTime) TotalPeriodSecond FROM (
    SELECT *, LAG(EventTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Device ORDER BY EventTime) EventTimeDown
    FROM (
        select
            *, LAG(UpTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Device ORDER BY EventTime) PUpTime
        from #Events
    ) q WHERE UpTime = 1 OR PUpTime = 1
) q WHERE UpTime = 1 AND PUpTime IS NOT NULL

DROP TABLE #Events
```

Comment: The link is fine, but please also include the relevant code within your answer. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Unnecessarily complex; https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=c291120d-e1cd-4459-af55-b1623a8982eb

Comment: That's very pretty, defo a more straightforward solution

Comment: Thank you very much Watson,  very useful also the link solution indicated by MatBailie.
I was also trying to use the LAG command as you suggested. 
Thank you all